# Issues with hangfire job activation and Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, hangfire

I'm triying to implement hangfire in my projects. I have a issue when I add a RecurringJob to hangfire, when it's fired i get this error:

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException
>
> The requested service
>   'XXXX.Services.ScheduleTasks.RepairNotificationSevice' has not been
>   registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to
>   provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.

I have installed hangfire and hangfire.autofac. I added hangfire configuration in my Startup.cs but my ContainerBuilder data is in another file. My startup.cs file look like:

```
app.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.UseSqlServerStorage("EmacIntranetEntities");
            config.UseServer();
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            config.UseAutofacActivator(builder.Build());
        });
```

It not works. I have check to paste all Container builder data between var builder and config.UseAutofacActivator without result. My Autofac configuration is in a file named "Bootstrapper.cs" called from Global.asax. How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
```

You have two separate autofac containers. You need to register the components you want your jobs to have access with. Also note if you using any database connections you are no longer in web mode and will not have access to the web request.

```
builder.RegisterModule<ServicesModule>();
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<XXXX.Services.ScheduleTasks.RepairNotificationSevice>().PropertiesAutowired().
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I not found any way to share the container object with autofac, therefore I've change autofac in favor of simple injector and change the initialization of the container in the startup.cs. All is Ok now. Thanks!

Comment: Not working :(...  get the error 'The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available'